# Shell Command to remove older files

Tags: shell, cron, centos, cpanel

I am making backups of a client's website on a remote FTP location. I have a script (usable without root access on cPanel) which is making backups on given cron and transfer it to remote ftp location. Now the real problem is starting; as we can't have unlimited gigabytes of disk space on any server so we have to limit the backups. I was finding shell command (which can be added to cronjob directly or by creating a bash script and call that script from cron. I want to keep 1 week's daily backups. I want to delete any backup from that directory which is older than 1 week. I found following command which looks promising

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +30 -exec rm  {}\;
```

But when I ran this command (for testing I replaced 'rm' with 'ls -l') I got following error

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

can anybody help to resolve this little issue?

I am running CentOS + cPanel

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

May be you just have to put space after the right bracket:

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +30 -exec rm  {} \;
```

I couldn't test on CentOS, but on my system it doesn't work if I don't put spaces around the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The semi-colon must be a separate argument (and a week is 7 days):

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +7 -exec rm {} ';'
```

Actually, you would probably do better to use the notation `+` in place of `;` as that will combine as many files names as convenient into a single command execution, rather like `xargs` does but without invoking `xargs`.  Hence:

```
find /path/to/files -mtime +7 -exec rm {} +
```

One other advantage of this is that there are no characters that must be protected from the shell.